# Python : Variable beginning by zero

Tags: python, string, variables, int, zero

When i want to assign a variable with value beginning by zero, with str the zero disappears.
Any idea how to assign a variable of number with zero at first.

Ex.

```
acc_id=018904837646
```

return :
SyntaxError: invalid token

**Edit**: with more details

In detail the id is returned by a row in a csv

```
acc_id = row['AccountId']
```

The row returns a int (18904837646) without zero, this int is used to retrieve dictionnary information `my_dict.get(acc_id).iteritems()`

But with int i have the error (`'NoneType' object has no attribute 'iteritems'`) so i converted to the str and it's with zero where the problem has appeared, maybe i have to look for how to use the dictionary with an int

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need that? You can have a number starting with `0`

Comment: only possible through str

Comment: do you need a string or an integer? you cannot have integers starting with zero. It's invalid. do you mean `MyVar="018904837646"`. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: this is because numbers are in `Octal numerical system`

Comment: @akashkarothiya only in python 2. In python 3 it's just illegal.

Comment: Yes forgot to mention that, thanks

Comment: @akashkarothiya For octal numbers in python 3 you have to use e.g. `0o123` instead of `0123`. Furhtermore, this can't be octal as it contains digits above 7.

Comment: But your dictionary, if it indeed has `int` keys, will also lose the leading zero. If you do: `my_dict[int("018904837646")] = "foo"` you'll be able to retrieve the value back with `my_dict[18904837646]` and if your `acc_id = "018904837646"` as a string, you'd still be able to retrieve the value from `my_dict` with: `my_dict[int(acc_id)]`. You just cannot have integers with leading 0 and you have to ensure that your `my_dict` keys are of the same type as your `acc_id` that you want to use for lookup.

Comment: "The row returns a int (018904837646)" it cannot return an int with leading zero. Print the type of what your function returns.

Answer (score -1):

This exception tells you, that the value of key `acc_id` is either None or not defined (`get(<key>)` returns None if the key is not found and no default is given). The `row['AccountId']` can't return an integer `018904837646` because this is invalid for type `int`. So either the return value here is a string (`"018904837646"`) or an `int` without leading zero (18904837646).

How does the key look like if you print the dict? Is it `"018904837646"` or `"18904837646"`? You have to adjust the id you get to the format of the key in your `dict`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer !
I have edited my question with more details